# How to change iFrame style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have this iframe:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="..." style="width: 90px; height: 70px">
</iframe>
```

How can I change the width ? Ive tried with:

```
$("#myiframe").attr("width", 104);
```

But the iframe is showing with a width of 90px.

How can I change that 90px ? Thanks!!!

Comment: You're confusing an attribute for a property. Attributes just set initial values. You want `HTMLIFrameElement.style.width`. Or, you could strip out the inline style attribute and use `HTMLIFrameElement.width` and `HTMLIFrameElement.height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myiframe").css({"width": 104});
```

Comment: @Johnathan's answer is nicer. I wrote it this way to show that styles are not attributes of the element, but need to be handled separately. However, the `width` function is cleaner in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method:

```
$("#myiframe").width(104);
```

Note that this method is both a getter, and a setter. Passing it a value will declare a width for the matched element, and passing no value will return the current width of the matched element.

```
alert( $("#myiframe").width() ); // 104
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/egozax/edit

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with changing the value inline?

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="..." style="width: 104px; height: 70px">
</iframe>
```

However, your jQuery code has a flaw: it's adding a `width` property to the iframe, it's not changing its `style`.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$("#myiframe").attr("width", "104px");
```

Comment: Attributes & properties are two different things.  The OP was trying to change a CSS Property by using jQuery's `attr()` method.